# Handle an argument beginning with "//"

Tags: vbscript

Passing an argument beginning with `//` (e.g. `//ABC`) to a VBS file (Wscript) results in an "Unknown Option" error.

How can I catch and handle this error?

Comment: Working for me, show us where it fails (source, the way you call it and the error)

Comment: @MC ND, Thank you for the reference. It works like a charm.

Comment: @Marged, I wrongly used \\ in my question. And you're right: that works.
I've edited the question to `//`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
Option Explicit

Dim i
For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Length - 1
    WScript.Echo i, WScript.Arguments(i)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 45765234.vbs one two three /a /b /c //D \\ABC
0 one
1 two
2 three
3 /a
4 /b
5 /c
6 \\ABC

e:\work\proj\soa\tmp
cscript 45765234.vbs one two three /a /b /c //D //ABC
Eingabefehler: Es wurde die unbekannte Option "//ABC" angegeben.
```

and:

```
cscript
Syntax: CScript Skriptname.Erweiterung [Option...] [Argumente...]

Optionen:
 //B            Batch-Modus: Zeigt keine Skriptfehler und Aufforderungen an
 //D            Aktives Debuggen aktivieren
 //E:engine     Modul zum Ausführen des Skripts verwenden
 //H:CScript    Ändert den Standardskripthost auf CScript.exe um
 //H:WScript    Ändert den Standardskripthost auf WScript.exe um (Standard)
 //I            Interaktiver Modus (Standard; Gegenteil von //B)
 //Job:xxxx     Führt einen WSF-Auftrag aus
 //Logo         Zeigt das Logo an (Standard)
 //Nologo       Zeigt kein Logo an: Bei Ausführung wird kein Banner angezeigt
 //S            Speichert die aktuellen Befehlszeilenoptionen für diesen Benutzer
 //T:nn         Timeout in Sekunden:  Maximale Zeit, die ein Skript laufen darf
 //X            Führt das Skript im Debugger aus
//U             Unicode für umgeleitete E/A-Vorgänge von der Konsole aus verwenden
```

And see: You can't use // or catch them in the script, because they are handled by the host (cscript.exe, wscript.exe). Using \, however, causes no problems.

Comment: @Marged, Just call any VBScript with `//ABC` and you'll get an `Unknown Option` error. *** @Ekkehard.Horner, my script gets the current line in Notepad++ as an argument. That "current line" might start with `//`. Thank you.